# In R, stopping a process without losing already run result?

Tags: r

I am doing an automated text analysis with stm package. The process is taking too long than I thought. I set up the command to run 10 models, but I only need 1. R already finished running 1 model, so I want to stop the process without losing already run result.

Is there any way that I can stop the 10 models process and preserve the first run model?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using RStudio ? Or another R interface ?

Comment: Don't think so, not without doing a memory dump with `gdb` and extracting what you need. In fact, I'm not confident even that would work. One alternative (seen after-the-fact) would be to right your code to do the 10 models, saving each *as it goes* instead of after all are done. I'm broken projects with >1M iterations into (much) smaller chunks and saved to a file with a timestamp in the name so that I can continue where I left off if interrupted.

Comment: You cannot preserve the data generated in **any** language on abort unless you've written code which saves results prior to the abort point.

Comment: If the result was saved to a list object, there might be hope.

Comment: You should more precise about the code you are running. There's a button in RStudio to interrupt R, it does not suit your wish ?